# Unexpected Integration Constant

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why does this integration

```
Integrate[15-30x+6x^2-1/(x+5),x]
```

return 700 as integration constant? If we make a slight modification

```
Integrate[15-30x+6x^2-1/(x-5),x]
```

Mathematica provides desired result.

EDIT:
It turns out that the aforementioned modification gives the wrong answer, instead of $15x-15x^2+2x^3-\log(x-5)$ it gives $15x-15x^2+2x^3-\log(5-x)$ even in Rubi. Try these

```
Integrate[-1/(x-5),x]
Int[1/(x-5),x]
```

I think we should add 'bug' tag in this integration problem.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect with the 700.  Differentiate the answer to check. (I assume you realize this.)  `Integrate` does not promise to satisfy a particular initial condition, and one should not expect it to.

Comment: Yes, but what about Integrate[-1/(x-5),x]?

Comment: `Integrate[-1/(x-5),x]` gives a correct answer, too.  What's the problem?  My point was that *Mathematica* does not specify the constant of integration, nor does it always give the simplest answer. The simplest one might be feasible, but it does not do it. All I think that you should be able to count on is that you get *some* antiderivative. If you don't, then it's a bug.  If one needs the antiderivative to satisfy some condition, then the constant needs to solved for.

Comment: i think it should be conditional expression, for $x \in (0,5)$ then $-\log(5-x)$ and for $x>5$ then $-\log(x-5)$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In *Mathematica* `x` and the answer are assumed to be complex.  So negative arguments are ok. `Log[u]` and `Log[-u]` differ by a constant.

Comment: Before we add "bug" tag, we should demonstrate the presence of a "bug".

Answer (score 6):

One has to look at code internals to find out. Most likely uncleared variable internally got stuck around. But since the result is still mathematically correct, one can't call this a bug. Strange, yes (why this integral and not others?), but still correct result.

But using [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) `Int` instead of `Integrate`, there is no constant of integration:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I recommend having Rubi package installed. I use it all the time, since it also shows the integration steps if needed which can be really useful sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the constant 700 is the result of the internal substitution x+5->t, needed for finding the Log.

```
Integrate[ 15 - 30 x + 6 x^2 - 1/(x + 5) /. x -> t - 5, t]
```

(* 315 t - 45 t^2 + 2 t^3 - Log[t] *)

```
Expand[%  /. t -> x + 5]
```

(* 700 + 15 x - 15 x^2 + 2 x^3 - Log[5 + x] *)